# Moving UITableViewCell to different section causing assertion failure

Tags: ios

I am trying to move a UITableViewCell in the first section of a UITableVIew to the first row of the second section, the one underneath, in this way:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:btn.tag];
NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:pathOfTheCell toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3232.3/UITableView.m:1383
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the complete error you are getting. If you look closely, you will notice that it complains about your data source returning data that doesn't match with the new section contents. You also have to reflect the changes in your data source.